# Databricks (SQL Warehouse) How to read data from postgres (jdbc)

Tags: jdbc, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-connect, databricks-sql

Trying to connect database sql warehouse from postgres db but the problem I am facing is that it shows me that data source is not supported.

Please see screenshot below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8bsi.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no source type `postgresql` in databricks. The only supported types are TEXT, AVRO, CSV, JSON, JDBC, PARQUET, ORC, DELTA, LIBSVM (https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-table-using.html)

Now, for your case, it is typical external data sourcing from a remote server or data location. For postgres, you can use the `JDBC` type. The implementation of that can be found in the relative documentation here https://docs.databricks.com/external-data/jdbc.html#language-sql

Comment: I've updated the question with screenshot of the JDBC query. But im getting the error

Comment: The url parameter should be a jdbc url. Test is not a valid url. More can be found here https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/use/#connecting-to-the-database

Comment: btw, you shouldn't alter the original problem in stackoverflow. if you do that, some people who ran into your original issue won't find the answer.  Update your question instead with a sequence of problems.

Comment: "Thanks for your response, i edited the properties with 'test' for confidentiality. The properties im using work perfectly when using pyspark. Sure ill be mindful of updating the question properly next time."

Comment: I am getting this error:
The input query contains unsupported data source(s). Only csv, json, avro, delta, parquet, orc, text, unity catalog data sources are supported on databricks sql

Comment: Ah I think you need to create the view first `CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW ` for JDBC. Then insert the view content into a physical table.